# Как сделать слайдер в телеграмм боте на python на инлайн кнопках

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как сделать так чтобы было как на картинке и можно было листать. Желательно пример с кодом, а то не могу понять как сделать.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnRDp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Сам не занимался слайдерами на inline кнопках, но понимаю как всё работает. Тут довольно просто. Для начала, Вам нужно получить id того сообщения, к которому необходимо прикрепить слайдер. Создаёте стандартно клавиатуру и прикрепляете её. Затем в обработчике функций нажатия на кнопку стрелки например влево, вставляете следующий код: `message_id = callback_query.message.message_id`. Это необходимо для получения id сообщения, к которому прикреплён слайдер. Далее используете метод `bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=, message_id=message_id, reply_markup=)`, где в аргументе `chat_id` вставляете код, для получения чата отправленного сообщения, оно же - `callback_query.message.sender_chat.id`, а в `reply_markup` передаёте следующую клавиатуру - страницу слайдера. Так же и с предыдущей.